# Passing std::array of different sizes to a function

Tags: c++

I have this code snippet in C:

```
int foo[5];
int bar[10];

Func(foo, _countof(foo));  // (_countof(x) is the size of the array x)
Func(foo, _countof(bar));

void Func(int p[], int count)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    // do something with p[i]
  }
}
```

I need to translate this into C++

My first thought was something like this:

```
std::array<int, 5> foo;
std::array<int, 10> bar;

Func(foo, foo.size());
// or even better:
Func(foo);
```

So far so good, but now I'm stuck with the `Func` function, I need to pass the `std::array` and the size, but `std::array<int, 5>` is not the same type as `std::array<int, 10>`.

```
void Func(std::array<int, ???> a, size_t count)
{

}
```

Is there an elegant way to solve this using `std::array`?

Do I need `Func` to be a function template?

I know how to do it with `std::vector` instead of `std::array`.

Comment: make func a template that is parametrized on the number of elements?

Comment: Write a templated function.

Comment: If you are going for a template, consider making it a template which takes a pair of iterators, like the standard library algorithms (or use ranges rather than just arrays)

Comment: It's a pity that a duplicate only includes one of the very appealing solutions as the last answer with 0 score (until upvoted by me). Because of that, I am going to highlight it here - a good way of doing that is to use a `span` from C++20, or `gsl::span`.